# Substring multiple lines of text

Tags: c#, substring

I have a text file containing these words:

> Name: Bob
>
> Age: 3

and my c# code is:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("path to a.txt");
```

How do i substring this so that i could get the value `3` and `Bob`?

Comment: `"Bob"` and `"3"` isn't a substring of your text. They are two substrings. You need to read [ask] and then try to make you question more precise.

Comment: Smells like [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/spec/)?

Comment: You can use Regex `Name: (\w*)` and `Age: (\d*)` per line.

Comment: You could also use IndexOf and Substring methods.

Comment: Is this a config file and you're trying to read the values based of the key? i.e. `"Name"` is the key and `"Bob"` is the value you want?

Comment: You can use [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `substring`

Comment: Regex is your best friend for such type of issues

Comment: @CodeNotFound... can you tell any good reference to learn Regex?

Comment: @Lucifer... can you tell any good reference to learn Regex?

Comment: @DudeCoder => [Learn by using C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) and to test it online [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: No effort, not code, no research, no reply in 30 minutes, 3 answers, this question smells like lazy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you're reading your data from a file, then this should work nicely:

```
Dictionary<string, string> pairs =
    File
        .ReadAllLines(@"50780830.txt")
        .Select(l => l.Split(':'))
        .Where(xs => xs.Length == 2)
        .Where(xs => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(xs[0].Trim()))
        .ToDictionary(xs => xs[0].Trim(), xs => xs[1].Trim());

Console.WriteLine(pairs["Name"]);
Console.WriteLine(pairs["Age"]);
```

When I run this I get:

```
Bob
3
```

Comment: Upvote for future proofing further SO questions with a dictionary, although the question is iffy to say the least

Comment: @TheGeneral - Agreed. The question needs improving. I asked the OP to do so, but they have gone AWOL.

Comment: You can replace `IsNullOrEmpty(xs[0].Trim())` with `IsNullOrWhitespace(xs[0])`

Comment: @CodeNotFound - I purposefully chose not to do that because on the next line I use `Trim()` and I wanted to remain consistent.

Comment: @Enigmativity Well, thanks for ur answer and as to the "iffy" question, I don't really know how to phrase a good question... even though I've read that how to that u linked me to.

Comment: @Denise - It was the general who called your question "iffy". I just suggest that you needed to make it more precise. The [ask] link is really quite detailed. I think if you followed the suggestions you'd be able to make the question a lot stronger. I hope it helps when you come to ask your next one.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) and `Substring` function just like this:

```
String str = "Name: Bob\r\n\r\nAge: 32";
String Name = str.Split(new String[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
Name = Name.Substring(Name.IndexOf(':') + 1).Trim();
String Age = str.Split(new String[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
Age = Age.Substring(Age.IndexOf(':') + 1).Trim();
Console.WriteLine(Name + "," + Age);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with only one line:

```
IEnumerable<String> list = str.Split('\n').Select(s => s.Split(':')[1]);
```

The first split meaning is to isolate each row.
The second split meaning is to take the word after ':'.

Comment: What if there is no value e.g. "Age :"? you'll get `IndexOutOfRangeException`:)

Comment: @CodeNotFound - you are absolutely right. He may do some index checks in addition, if case he need it (maybe he verify that issue before)

Comment: @CodeNotFound I don't seem to be getting any exception with `Age :`